# Is it possible to move a collection view cell in storyboard?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, storyboard

[This is the my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hn33.png)

I want my collection of images to begin in the middle of the view. I know I can simply half the size of the view but I need to make an animation that expands the view to fit the full VC. Is there a property feature in the storyboard that can do this?

Comment: Check this sample project. It contain animations that could help. `github.com/seedante/CollectionViewAnimation`